# After subdividing a painted cube, how many smaller cubes have paint on exactly 2 sides?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

> A solid cube of side 6 is first painted pink and then cut into smaller cubes of side 2. How many of the smaller cubes have paint on exactly 2 sides?

Answer with illustrations will be helpful for me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Think of a Rubik's cube ([image source](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~mec/Winter2009/Lipa/Puzzles/lesson2.html))

[image]

(just imagine that the center is also a cube, not [a turning mechanism like it is in real life](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQpp3.jpg)).

How many cubes have two stickers?

Comment: is there have 12?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Do you understand why this is the right picture for your question?

Comment: yup got it, but it's hard to it by hand :( cause drawing the picture is kinda hard.